# Callback 404 not found in login with google with Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have this link on my modal popup

```
<li><a href="{{ route('auth/google') }}" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
```

and routes is

```
Route::get('google', 'SocialiteAuthController@googleRedirect')->name('auth/google');
Route::get('/auth/google-callback',  'SocialiteAuthController@loginWithGoogle');
```

[image]

Services.php

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/google/callback',
],
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;

class SocialiteAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function googleRedirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

     /**
     * Facebook login authentication
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function loginWithGoogle()
    {
        try {
            $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
            $user = User::where('google_id', $googleUser->id)->first();

            if($user){
                Auth::login($user);
                return redirect('/home');
            }

            else{
                $createUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $googleUser->name,
                    'email' => $googleUser->email,
                    'fb_id' => $googleUser->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('test@123')
                ]);

                Auth::login($createUser);
                return redirect('/home');
            }

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            dd($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> Guard :

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

but when i login i'm getting this page 404 not found

[image]

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: As you defined redirect URL in the `services.php` file is not matched with your route for callback `/auth/google-callback`

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya: I have added the screen shot please check both are same

Comment: No, not the same.  Redirect URL is `login/google/callback` and route is `auth/google-callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the routes file

```php
Route::get('/auth/google-callback',  'SocialiteAuthController@loginWithGoogle');
```

but you defined

```php
http://localhost:8000/login/google/callback
```

then the route must be the same as the one you defined in the redirect url and google api settings. Change the routes method to the one you defined

```php
Route::get('/login/google/callback',  'SocialiteAuthController@loginWithGoogle');
```